# Auth0 SMS Passwordless Login receive @@password@@ as verification code in the SMS OTP message

Tags: auth0

I have configured password less login using both email and sms in Auth0. I have followed thru this guide **https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/passwordless/authentication-methods/sms-otp** and also the API doc **https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?http#passwordless**.
I use Postman to call the API **https://abc.au.auth0.com/passwordless/start**
Content-Type: application/json

```
Body: {
  "client_id": "00999uj3q098dfkhjvdfrYyAmjm",
  "client_secret": "3VMQZVkT7264riuhnfvhdfvLwyEy",
  "connection": "email",
  "phone_number": "abc@mail.com",
  "send": "code"
}
```

and I am able to receive the correct verification like 123456 in the email inbox.

However, when I switch to send SMS OTP and change the body like below:

```
{
  "client_id": "00999uj3q098dfkhjvdfrYyAmjm",
  "client_secret": "3VMQZVkT7264riuhnfvhdfvLwyEy",
  "connection": "sms",
  "phone_number": "+61889908554",
  "send": "code"
}
```

I am able to receive the SMS in my phone. However, the verification code is @@password@@ instead of 6 digits number.

I really have no idea what I miss configuring. I have successfully link my Twilio account in my Auth0.

Comment: Thank you so much for the docs provided.
This one helped me: https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?http#get-code-or-link

Answer (score 0):

[image: auth0 passwordless SMS OTP]

change @@password@@ to {{code}}
I cannot believe auth0 make such a cheap mistake